# webbrowser library is not working as intended on SikulixIDE

Tags: python, jython, sikuli, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

On SikulixIDE, the library webbrowser always open the default browser, even when i use the get method, i tried my code on regular python, it does work. Anyone know why it is reacting like that ?

```
webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open(myurl)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get  *and* table what can be passed to  `get()` is listed below `register()`

Comment: @rasjani Thanks a lot for the reply, but that ain't working either, that's why I put the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by automating it using a python file and running it trough cmd with base python.exe.